# Wrong outcome with sql replace statement

Tags: sql-server

When I use the following formule:

```
,replace(
replace(
replace(
replace(
replace(
replace(
replace(
replace(
replace(
replace(
replace(
replace(str(datepart(m,PMCCONTRACT.STATUSDATE),2),'1','januari')
,'2','februari')
,'3','maart')
,'4','april')
,'5','mei')
,'6','juni')
,'7','juli')
,'8','augustus')
,'9','september')
,'10','oktober')
,'11','november')
,'12','december')
```

It goes well until oktober. After that I get: januari0, januarijanuari and januariifebruari instead of oktober, november, december.

What can I do to get oktober, november and december.

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help us help you. This feels like an XY Problem though; why are you replacing month names with month numbers?

Comment: The statement `SELECT REPLACE(STR(datepart(m, DATEFROMPARTS(2020, 11, 1))), '1', 'January')` that returns `JanuaryJanuary` explains the problem.

Comment: just do replacement of 10, 11 and 12 month first

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just use a `CASE` expression instead of that `replace()` mess.

```
CASE datepart(m, pmccontract.statusdate)
  WHEN 1 THEN
    'januari'
  ...
  WHEN 12 THEN
    'december'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Feels like your approach is wrong here. If all you want is the month name, why not convert the name to a date, and then select the part? We don't know what your data looks like, but I assume this will put you on the right track:

```
SET LANGUAGE BRITISH; --Note that you won't need this, I use this as your default language is clearly not English based but i am using English month names

CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (YourMonth varchar(15));

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
VALUES('January'),('February'),('May')

SELECT DATEPART(MONTH,CONCAT('01 ', YourMonth, ' 2000'))
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b663eaf5cbfbd51e1f6566ab27b6a5bc)